# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

> This is my json parameter which I have checked..it is correct

```
 {
        "ticketID": "0",
        "consumerNo": "",
        "issueDescription": "amount is wrong",
        "isBill": "1",
        "billOrReceiptNumber": "13",
        "issueTypeFId": "1",
        "issueSubTypeFId": "1",
        "otherType": "",
        "otherSubtype": "",
        "billType": "1",
        "isRc": "0",
        "supportToConsumerDescription": "",
        "consumerToSupportDescription": "",
        "supportToRCdescription": "",
        "userFId": "",
        "newstatus": "0",
        "oldStatus": "0",
        "newAssignee": "",
        "oldAssignee": "",
        "isConsumerAsked": "0",
        "isConsumerReplied": "0",
        "fileuploads": "",
        "comment": "New Ticket Added",
        "secretKeys": "33MsbZsPaEKJkgLvfynAeiGMwhJzJ1Rfr9WUxwya9KYy5wyWz0fkbUblMF0fU3BC0KNObdPFLoQiNgKkSttZgO7bRbvoRfy1OJjVx9r+1DQ="
    }
```

> But still it is throwing error..I am unable tofind solution
> please tell me where I am wrong
>
> Here is my c# code for executing function

```
        DataTable retOg = new DataTable();
            var client = new RestClient(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["links"].ToString() + functionName);
            client.Timeout = -1;

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", param, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            string res = response.Content;
            dynamic jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
```

> Server response in res string

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
 the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
 information about the error and where it originated in the code.
 
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method
addEditTickets. Parameter name: methodName
```

Comment: Can you post string res pls?

Comment: its very lengthy..not able to post here

Comment: Yes, the Json is valid, but is seems your _request_ using that Json is not valid. If you can’t post _why_ the server says it’s not valid, then how can anyone help you? (Hint: don’t try and post it as a comment, edit your question to include the server response)

Comment: Very often this error is because your response is HTML instead of json. Could be a 500 or 404, 401, etc. Read the HTML that is returned for clues.

Comment: @NoorinAnsari You have an error in res string, so how are we going to help you if you don't post at least a part of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the JSON parsing exception because the server is returning a text response (which you've listed in your question).

> Unknown web method addEditTickets. Parameter name: methodName

Based on the error, it seems that the URL you're trying to use is invalid. Verify that the URL you're constructing is valid; it appears that `functionName` does not contain the correct value in this expression:

```cs
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["links"].ToString() + functionName
```